# how can i handle long datatype null value into specific output like we use nvl()

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle10g

There is one column whose datatype is long().
in this the data are null so how can I handle the null value in desired output like string or one single number.

I want to handle long() datatype null value in select statement.
use the nvl(res,0)  where res column datatype is long.so I got the error

ora-00932:iconsistent datatype: expected Long got number

Answer (score 0):

the 0 in the NVL is not a LONG but a NUMBER,
LONG type is obsolete even if stil present in a lot of meta tables and has nothing to do with the Java, C, ... "long" types : it's a textual type to be replaced by CLOB or VARCHAR2(up to 32K), if you have extended mode enabled.

Comment: but still unable to get how to handle the null in the long datatype. what should be the function i can use except  nvl( )

Comment: Example of converting LONG to VARCHAR2: 

select index_name, column_position,
dbms_lob.substr(sys_dburigen(index_owner, index_name, column_position, column_expression, 'text()').getclob(),4000,1) as ce
from all_ind_expressions ;